# Reload an EMF model resource when the XML file is changed manually

Tags: editor, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have an EMF editor linked with a file `spring.xml`.

When the editor is opened the Spring model is created and stores in the editing domain.

How can I load the updated Spring model into the editing domain resource every time a user manually edits and adds content into `spring.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at  resourcechangedlistener. You will get control automatically when  some one changes the file in editing domain.